# Optics, What is a Foil?

Tags: optics, optical-materials

I was using a program for simulating optical elements; mirrors, gratings, foils, crystals, slits, and zoneplates are what it mentioned. Does anyone know what a foil is in terms of optics? I know what aluminum foil is, obviously, but in terms of an optical system I don't know what a foil, or foil, would be, and what it's unique optical properties are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a black coating to stick on surfaces of devices of an optical setuo to reduce spurious reflections.

So it's very very black ("99,99%") on one side, and possibly sticky on the other side.

For an example, see 
[Edmund Optics: Acktar Light Absorbent Foil](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.edmundoptics.de%2Flab-production%2Fgeneral-tools%2Facktar-light-absorbent-foil%2F3634&ei=7ZmOU-SDJ4TvPLjogKgL&usg=AFQjCNHEGE3Bwe2H_y4EhZ_nVlANaRELzA&sig2=rmg_Hj1Urav_6mRIu0GyaA&bvm=bv.68235269,d.ZWU&cad=rja)